# Filtering multiple tags

Tags: json, angular

So I have this as my data.
I want to be able to get all the tags without repeating.
Is there anyway I can get that from the JSON using Angular?

```
var data = [
  { "id" : 1, 
     "title" : "title 1", 
     "description" : "Lorem Ipsum.", 
     "tags" : [
        { "tag": "facebook" },
        { "tag": "twitter" }
     ]
  }, 
  { "id" : 2, 
     "title" : "title 2", 
     "description" : "Lorem Ipsum.", 
     "tags" : [
        { "tag": "google" },
        { "tag": "twitter" }
     ]
  },
  { "id" : 3, 
     "title" : "title 3", 
     "description" : "Lorem Ipsum.", 
     "tags" : [
        { "tag": "reddit" },
        { "tag": "instagram" }
     ]
  }, 
  { "id" : 4, 
     "title" : "title 4", 
     "description" : "Lorem Ipsum.", 
     "tags" : [
        { "tag": "reddit" },
        { "tag": "9gag" }
     ]
  }
]
```

I expect the output of the code to be:
var tags = [ "facebook", "twitter", "google", "reddit", "instagram", "9gag" ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to share my solution since some solutions are using features not supported by all browsers. 
Here is how to reduce your array to an array of strings with only your tag information

```js
var data = [{"id": 1, "title": "title 1", "description": "Lorem Ipsum.", "tags": [{ "tag":"facebook" }, { "tag": "twitter" } ]},{"id": 2,"title": "title 2","description": "Lorem Ipsum.","tags": [{ "tag": "google" }, { "tag": "twitter" } ]},{"id": 3,"title": "title 3","description": "Lorem Ipsum.","tags": [ { "tag": "reddit" }, { "tag": "instagram" } ]},{ "id": 4,"title": "title 4","description": "Lorem Ipsum.","tags": [{ "tag":"reddit" },{ "tag":"9gag" }]}
];
   var result= data.map( (d)=> d.tags  )
         .reduce((a,b)=> a.concat(b),[])
         .reduce((e,f)=> { 
              if (!e.join().includes(f.tag)){  
                 e.push(f.tag); 
              } return e;  } 
         ,[]);
         
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

And there is such an ordinary simple method. Using forEach and findIndex.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "title 1",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum.",
    "tags": [
      { "tag": "facebook" },
      { "tag": "twitter" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "title 2",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum.",
    "tags": [
      { "tag": "google" },
      { "tag": "twitter" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "title 3",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum.",
    "tags": [
      { "tag": "reddit" },
      { "tag": "instagram" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "title 4",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum.",
    "tags": [
      { "tag": "reddit" },
      { "tag": "9gag" }
    ]
  }
];



let uniqTags = getUniqTags(data);
console.log(uniqTags);

function getUniqTags(data) {
  let res = [];
  data.forEach(d => {
    d.tags.forEach(f => {
      let fIndex = res.findIndex(r => r === f.tag);
      if (fIndex === -1) {
        res.push(f.tag)
      }
    });
  });
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with a [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) operation.

The `flatMap()` operation will collect all the tags from the various objects, while collecting them in a `Set` will remove the duplicates.

```
const tags = [...new Set(data.flatMap(d => d.tags.map(t => t.tag)))];
```

---

Complete snippet:

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "title 1",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum.",
    "tags": [{
        "tag": "facebook"
      },
      {
        "tag": "twitter"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "title 2",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum.",
    "tags": [{
        "tag": "google"
      },
      {
        "tag": "twitter"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "title 3",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum.",
    "tags": [{
        "tag": "reddit"
      },
      {
        "tag": "instagram"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "title 4",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum.",
    "tags": [{
        "tag": "reddit"
      },
      {
        "tag": "9gag"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const tags = [...new Set(data.flatMap(d => d.tags.map(t => t.tag)))];

console.log(tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flatMap() with map().And Use Set() to remove duplicates.

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "title 1",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum.",
    "tags": [{
        "tag": "facebook"
      },
      {
        "tag": "twitter"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "title 2",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum.",
    "tags": [{
        "tag": "google"
      },
      {
        "tag": "twitter"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "title 3",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum.",
    "tags": [{
        "tag": "reddit"
      },
      {
        "tag": "instagram"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "title 4",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum.",
    "tags": [{
        "tag": "reddit"
      },
      {
        "tag": "9gag"
      }
    ]
  }
]

let result = new Set(data.flatMap(ele => [...ele.tags]).map(el => el.tag));
console.log([...result])
```